# Equifax credit report insurance quotations

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, insurance, credit-history, car-insurance

I have just ordered a credit report from equifax. The **credit report shows up all healthy except for a large number of (genuine) 'insurance quotations'**.

These are car insurance quotations that I have been getting through online comparison sites for the last few months, as I have been deciding on what car to purchase. As I found suitable cars, I got quotations for the car insurance, through several comparison sites:

MoneySupermarket
Gocompare
comparethemarket
and a few direct ones (directline, aviva, admiral etc)

I do recall using the google car insurance search in the past as well as tesco's car insurance search.

Doing this for 5 or 6 different cars in the last few months, and going back and playing with the parameters (fully-comprehensive, 3rd party, job role etc) - seems to have kept almost 2 A4 pages of "credit search" history on my credit report - all of them marked as '**insurance quotation**'

Will this affect my credit rating or ability to get credit (i.e. mortgage) in the course of the next few years?

Also, why do car insurance search show up in my credit history? Surely they do not need to check my credit history, but rather my driving history. If I've defaulted in the past on a loan - it will not affect my driving (lest I try and do a speedy getaway from the debt collector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Companies can check credit reference agency files for a range of reasons beyond actual credit applications, such as identity verification.

As Equifax themselves [explain it](https://equifaxuk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/631/kw/insurance%20quotation/session/L3RpbWUvMTQwNDk4NTczNS9zaWQvYThReXlXWWw%3D):
"The reason the financial companies undertake these checks is to verify that applicants are real, that they are not likely to commit fraud and, where the company offers credit , to ensure the customer has the means to pay back the loan"

However these checks should not have any impact on your credit rating, for the simple reason that other companies should not see them.  Checks made for reasons other than actual credit applications are sometimes referred to as "soft" checks - these checks are only visible to you and the company that made the check.

Checks made for actual credit applications are "hard" and are shown to other companies querying your record for credit applications.

From the same Equifax link:
"It is important to remember that this type of check is a soft check and the record it leaves on your file is only visible by the company that undertook the check and you."

Answer (score 4):

> Will this affect my credit rating or ability to get credit (i.e. mortgage) in the course of the next few years?

Nope. Insurance quotation searches get deleted on a timely basis, in a year or so if I remember correctly. My home insurance quotation searches also showed up on my searches list, every time I made one.

> Also, why do car insurance search show up in my credit history?

Why shouldn't they ? If you have committed insurance fraud or have an adverse credit history or have CCJs against you, it all shows up in your credit report. Primarily doing a credit history search is much easier and easily availabe. Some people take up insurance to do insurance fraud, which willn't show in your driving records but in your credit history.